# Peek stdin using pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads, stdin

I'm trying to peek stdin to see if anything is there using pthreads.  I (think I) need to do this because if there is nothing in std in, stream access functions will block for input.

I feel the way to do this is to fire off a pthread that checks stdin, and sleep(1) and see if the thread found anything.

Here's what I have so far.  If nothing is piped into the program then it will sleep as expected, but if something is in stdin the thread never gets fired.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void *checkStdIn(void *d){
    char c = '\0';
    c = cin.peek();
    if (c){
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, checkStdIn, NULL);
    if (rc){
        cerr << "Error no. " << rc << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sleep(2); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program ends before it can execute the thread.

Comment: Why doesn't sleep() remedy it though?

Comment: Your thread checks the input once, finds nothing and terminates.

Comment: @Ty: If you want to wait for the thread to finish, use phthread_join

Comment: Forget my previous comment, it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need pthreads for that and you can use `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to known if you can peek the stdin without blocking your application. For that I coded the `my_peek()` function which you just need to pass the number of seconds you want to wait for the input (you can even pass 0 if you don't want to wait):

```
/* According to POSIX.1-2001 */
#include <sys/select.h>

/* According to earlier standards */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

int
my_peek(unsigned int nsecs)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set rfds;
    int fd;

    // stdin file descriptor is 0
    fd = 0;

    timeout.tv_sec = nsecs;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

    if (select(fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0)
        return std::cin.peek();
    return -1;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int peek;

    peek = my_peek(2);
    if (peek != -1) {
        std::cout << "we could peek without freezing" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "my_peek() returned " << peek << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "we could not peek without freezing" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that it is BAD to rely on `select(2)` to tell if there is data in the `cin` object or `stdin` `FILE` structure because, as Nemo stated, they are BUFFERED. The best thing to do is avoid "cin" in this example using `read(2)`. The improved version of `my_peek()` would look like:

```
int
my_peek(unsigned int nsecs)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set rfds;
    int fd;
    unsigned char c;

    // stdin file descriptor is 0
    fd = 0;

    timeout.tv_sec = nsecs;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

    if (select(fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) <= 0)
        return -1;
    if (read(fd, &c, 1) != 1)
        return -1;
    return static_cast<int>(c); /* or "return (int)c" for C-only programs */
}
```

For more information please check the `select(2)` manual page at http://linux.die.net/man/2/select.

PS: You could try to rely on the value returned by the `std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` as explained in the cpluplus site http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/in_avail/, or even in the `readsome()` method of the `istream` class, but they usually depend on the `FILE` buffer which is not exposed in the GNU C++ library. Don't do it or you might fail.

Comment: This is by far the best answer for a pthreads-capable environment if you're on a POSIX-capable platform. No need to spawn a thread when the OS can just tell you what the state is on a file descriptor. (+1)

Comment: Except `std::cin` is usually buffered, so this is not going to work in general.  (Try peek+read in a loop one character at a time, redirect stdin from a file, and you will see what I mean.)

Comment: Thanks, Nemo. I fixed the example and added tips to avoid buffer issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep(2)` is worthless because it does not guarantee that your thread will finish within 2 microseconds prior to program termination. You need to implement `pthread_join(thread, NULL);` to wait for the thread to finish. See here for a good [pthread](http://www.amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html) example.

Also, cin.peek() will block waiting for input. That is how it is designed. See here for an example of [cin.peek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/peek/).

Comment: `sleep` time is actually in whole seconds, but one needs to join anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Bawh, ninja'd by Fernando :)

Okay, so I'm not 100% sure on what the best answer will be for you because I can't tell what you want your program to eventually *do*.

First and foremost, this is not the kind of problem that should be solved using threads. Threads are not the catch-all solution to everything and generally have huge overhead compared to other solutions. Because you're already using `pthreads`, I'll assume Windows compatibility isn't an issue.

The first step is to disable canonical mode, which will allow you to gett characters without having to wait for `enter`. If you were 100% sure `stdin` won't ever be a terminal, you can skip this step.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h>

void toggle_canonical(bool on) {
    struct termios terminal_settings;

    // Get the existing terminal settings
    tcgetattr(0 /* stdin */, &terminal_settings);
    if(on) {
        // Disable canonical mode
        terminal_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
        // Read at least one character.
        terminal_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    } else {
        // Enable canonical mode
        terminal_settings.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    }
    tcsetattr(0 /* stdin */, TCSANOW, &terminal_settings);

    return;
}

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    // The read timeout, which can be 0 if you don't want to block at all.
    struct timeval to = {5 /* seconds */, 0 /* miliseconds */};
    fd_set read_fds;
    int ret = 0;

    // Turn canonical mode on
    toggle_canonical(true);

    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(0, &read_fds);

    // The first parameter to select() is the highest file
    // descriptor in the set + 1, so in this case because
    // STDIN == 0, we pass 1. This is actually completely
    // ignored on several platforms, including Windows.
    if((ret = select(1, &read_fds /* read set */, NULL /* write set */, NULL /* error set */, &to /* timeout */)) == 0) {
        std::cout << "You didn't type anything in time." << std::endl;
    } else if (ret == 1) {
        std::cout << "Yay, you typed something in time!" << std::endl;
    } else if (ret == -1) {
        std::cout << "Oh no, an error occured!" << std::endl;
    }

    // Turn canonical mode off
    toggle_canonical(false);
    return 0;
}
```