# Interrupt a getLine() while loop in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop, getline

I made a console applications that accepts commands from two sources:

1. The actual console -> this is a while(getLine()) loop in a seperate thread.
2. A websocket server -> this also runs on a seperate thread

If there is a command entered, the command is stored in a vector until another while loop (that runs every 20ms) loops trough all the commands entered in the time passed. If he reads a command, he executes it.

Now, there is a Stop command who stops the application. When entered, the application shuts down as expected. But the problem is: this takes some time, and you can still enter text from the first command source (getline()). Once you type something, the shutdown sequence stops, and waits until you pressed enter.

I terminate the first thread (that contains the getline loop) once the shutdown sequence starts. But that doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't do that, because that thread doesn't know, and when he get's that message, it's already too late...

Comment: I can't upload code existing from 50 classes and headers. I tried to explain the structure as good as possible. My code isn't needed, I just need a way to cancel a getline() action that is looping in a  while. If you really think the code is needed, I'll try to post the relevant pieces.

Answer (score 0):

`getline()` is a blocking call, you'll probably have to use something different, if you want to receive messages (i.e. a shut down command) from other threads. You did not mention which library you use for multithreading and how you terminate the console reading thread (it's possible, that your way of stopping the thread still does not force it to exit from `getline`)

This question seems to have some relevant answers: [Peek stdin using pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848128/peek-stdin-using-pthreads)

By the way, you mentioned a vector, which is (if I understood it correctly) accessed from multiple threads. You'll have to take care about proper synchronization (e.g. using a mutex when accessing the vector).

Also, the fact that you have some kind of loop, which "polls" the vector every 20 ms is indicating that you may have some flaws in overall design of your application. Try to get rid of it by using more appropriate means for passing events between threads, such as condition variables.

Comment: I use the standard C++ libraries for threads. To add a string to the vector I use a mutex, so no problems there. For the loop that runs every 20ms: I don't see an alternative, because there will be more threads that will be sending commands. And what do you mean with 'using something different'. I looked trough cin >> but it does the same: it waits until input is given.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getline` is a blocking call and will return just after you press ENTER in case of stdin.

I had a similar problem and solved it as shown below. 
I used two file descriptors: one to monitor the stdin and an other to monitor a "self-pipe". The latter acts as a trigger to unlock the `select` in case some event happens. The former ensures `getline` is called just once it can read a full line.

```
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int pipe_fd[2];
auto p = pipe(pipe_fd);
auto stdin_fd = fileno(stdin); // 0

fd_set check_fd;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FD_ZERO(&check_fd);
    FD_SET(stdin_fd, &check_fd);
    FD_SET(pipe_fd[0], &check_fd);

    auto t1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        uint32_t dummy = 43;
        // this will stop the data input
        write(pipe_fd[1], &dummy, sizeof(dummy));
    });

    auto maxfd = pipe_fd[0] > pipe_fd[1] ? pipe_fd[0] : pipe_fd[1];
    select(maxfd + 1, &check_fd, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (FD_ISSET(stdin_fd, &check_fd))
    {
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::cout << "You enterd:" << input << std::endl;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(pipe_fd[0], &check_fd))
        std::cout << "Event" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```